# How to save a string that contain ' into PostgreSQL

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I use PostgreSQL  as database in my application which uses Java . When I try to insert a string into a field which is of the type `text`, an exception is thrown if the string contain  `'`. The exception I am getting is :

```
Hibernate: update public.slider_group set slid_grou_title=?, slid_grou_short_desc=?, site_id=?, status=?, update_date=?, no_slide=?, pos_type=?, widget_type=?, custom_html=? where slid_grou_id=?
20:47:12.476 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] ERROR o.h.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Batch entry 0 update public.slider_group set slid_grou_title= was aborted. Call getNextException() to see the cause.
20:47:12.476 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] ERROR o.h.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"

20:47:12.522 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] ERROR o.h.e.d.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:375) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
```

I have not added the entire exception message here.
Is there any way I can save a string to the database even if it contains `'`

This is the hibernate query and the object "widgetContentTo" has the field which contain the string to be saved into the corresponding field in the DB

```
public void saveOrUpdateWidgetContent(WidgetContentTo widgetContentTo) throws HibernateException {
    try {
        getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(widgetContentTo);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

class corresponding to the object I am trying to save to database:

```
  public class WidgetContentTo
    {
        private int             widgetContentId;
        private int     siteId;
        private String      widgetContentName;
        private String      widgetContentShortDesc;
        private int             noWebcontents;
        private String      status;
        private Timestamp   timeCreated;
        private Timestamp   updateDate;
        private String      posType;
        private String      widgetType;
        private String      customHtml;
    }
```

If the last field, customHtml contain single quotes, I get an exception. I tried to replace single quotes as follows:

```
   String data = widgetContentTo.getCustomHtml();
    data = data.replace("'", "\'");
    widgetContentTo.setCustomHtml(data);
```

The name of the table in the database is `slider_group` and the field corresponding to `customHtml` is `custom_html` and datatype `text`

Comment: Escape `'` with `\'`. Do it for all other such characters before saving to db.

Comment: Have you set `hibernate.dialect` correctly?

Comment: @jaycp: You shouldn't need to do that in the application code - that's the ORM's job.

Comment: Please show the code you're using to insert the record.

Comment: ' public void saveOrUpdateWidgetContent(WidgetContentTo widgetContentTo) throws HibernateException
   {
    try
     {
      getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(widgetContentTo);
     }
    catch (Exception ex)
     {
      System.out.println(ex);
     }
   }'
This is the hibernate query and the object  "widgetContentTo" has the field which contain the string to be saved into the corresponding field in the DB  @Jon Skeet

Comment: @edwiser, please edit the question, don't post relevant information in comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not relying on anything to escape for you, the escape character you're looking for is: `\`

Example:

```
SELECT  trequests.reqid, 
FROM lngprtl.tbranches
WHERE tbranches.branchid = '\'test\''
```

---

The above select will return results where branch ID is equal to `'test'`

Comment: He has `hibernate` tag in his question, why do you think that there is some hand-written SQL in his code?

Comment: The point is that the OP shouldn't *need* to escape anything, because Hibernate should be doing it all for them.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30809307/how-to-save-s-string-containing-single-quotes-to-column-of-datatype-text-of-a-ta] is a similar instance